# Check if directory was loaded from cache in Gitlab CI

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration

I want to set the value of a variable based on whether loading from a cache has succeeded.
I plan to set the variable using an if statement, the same way they do in this example: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#workflowrulesvariables
(The link goes to the wrong part of the page: search for Example of workflow:rules:variables )
If my yaml looks like this:

```
cache:
    key: $CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
    paths:
    - pathtocache
```

How can I check if pathtocache exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible due to the lifecycle of when rules are evaluated, which is before the cache/artifacts are restored. Keep in mind the rules can be used to define whether or not the job runs, so they are evaluated at pipeline start before any jobs have been run and thus before you would have generated any cache files.

If you want to test whether the cache has been populated then branch your job's logic based on that, you will have to do so within the `script` block for your job.

Comment: Is there something I can put in the yaml, or am I better off writing a python script or something to see if the directory I want has appeared? I'm trying the second way, but seeing no results yet.

Comment: You're better off with the second way, unfortunately. There just isn't anything you can put in the YAML because the cache will never load before your rules evaluate. Anything you'd put there would have a 0% chance of having the cache loaded on time. You could use a "before_script" to keep your python/bash scripting separate from the rest of your script though.

Comment: I ended up writing a bash script.